# Extract a grid from a one-dimentional array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, grid

I have an array with 12 values and I need to display these in a grid like this (always 4 columns, 3 rows):

```
  1  |  2  |  3  |  4
 ----------------------
  5  |  6  |  7  |  8
 ----------------------
  9  |  10 |  11 |  12
```

I am looping through the **grid** and I have two coordinates: column and row.

How do I know which index belongs to which row and column? I tried several things, but they are not working:

```
objectAtIndex: (row + 1) * (column + 1) - 1
objectAtIndex: row + column
```

etc...

---

Row and column indexes start with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forward conversion: `objectAtPosition(x,y) = array[columns*y + x]`

provided `x<columns && y<rows`

backward conversion: `positionAtIndex(i) = (row=(i div columns), col=(i mod columns))`

note that `div` and `mod` correspond to integer operators `/` and `%` in C languages.